# How to disable Device monitoring in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 1.2 came up with new Future of device monitoring, it automatically starts monitoring the device when you plug it in, even if your app is not running.

I notice that it slow down the work in Android Studio(Not that it is Speedy Gonzales right now...). It shows a progress for monitoring, that never finish.

How do I turn it off?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest removing the copyrighted artwork and explaining more about what this "Future of device monitoring" is.

Comment: @CommonsWare Look at the screen shoot

Comment: Are you running Android Studio 1.2? I'm not seeing those on 1.1. If you hide the CPU and/or Memory tabs (click the right-pointing arrow on the tab), does that fix things?

Comment: @CommonsWare didn't worked. Only when I close the monitoring process, it helps. But I don't want to do this each time. I don't want it to be turn on at all.

Comment: same problem - in constantly 'monitors' my device connected, eating cpu. I need only when I want it, not all the time. Couldn't find the turning off possibility in settings. Android Studio 1.2 Beta.

Answer (score 3):

So all you need to do is:

Open Tools -> Android -> uncheck **"Enable ADB Integration"**

[image]

NB! If you *debug* application, AS will enable ADB integration back.

Comment: It indeed do not show CPU and Memory, also the snap shot and the kill device buttons no longer working. But it continue to run the process of "Monitoring device".

Comment: Disabling adb integration is a radical solution. I need the integration for debugging, e.g.